# removeEditor failing on some editors

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some google apps script code that adds Editors to a document with no problem. However, when I run the following code I find that some of the editors are removed, and some error with the following message: "Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

```
var file = DocsList.getFileById( fid );
var editors = file.getEditors();

  for ( el = 0; el < editors.length ; el++ ) {
      file.removeEditor( editors[ el ] );
}
```

Given that the editors are retrieved from the file itself, and then fail to be removed, I cannot see how to progress this, as the error message offers no help.

Has anyone experienced similar. I cannot see any issues raised against this.

Thanks in advance.
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put your `file.remove(editors[ el ])` in a try-catch structure to catch the error (and see it) and let your app finish in every case.

Example :

```
function myFunction() {

var file = DocsList.getFileById( '0AnqS........bW1DNnVBbVE' );
var editors = file.getEditors();

Logger.log(editors.join())

  for ( el = 0; el < editors.length ; el++ ) {

      try{      

      file.removeEditor( editors[ el ] );
      Logger.log(editors[el]+' removed');// this editor is successfully removed

      } catch(error)

      {Logger.log('error on el = '+editors[el]+' = '+error)

      }
      }
}
```

*This of course brings no answer on your issue but it could help to see what is happening in more details, which editor gets an error and which doesn't.*

Answer (score 0):

I have the same experience, both removeEditor and removeViewer can fail for some users, despite obtaining the user object from the getViewers or getEditors methods.

My observation is that unless the returned user object is a Google apps account holder then the remove action will fail.

So, on a google apps domain example.com a file might be shared with the following email addresses:

```
normal_account@example.com
group_account@example.com
third_party@some_other_example.com
```

removeEditor/removeViewer will only succeed for the first address on the list.

Although the call to getEditors/getViewers returns a list of user objects, some of the objects appear empty eg user.getEmail() returns a blank string, which is what the API documentation says will happen https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/user#getEmail%28%29 if the email address is not available.